# NSCoding encode Array of Objects

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to encode an array containing multiple instances of a custom `NSObject` class. However, upon doing so, it returns a crash with message :

> -[Person encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8ff2c50

the class contains multiple properties and to store them as a collection is the purpose of the class.

the encoder method upon which it crashes is such:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder 
{
    [encoder encodeObject:_arrayOfPeople forKey:@"DataStoragePeopleArray"];
}
```

Comment: You need to encode you NSObject Class Properties too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement the `NSCoding` protocol in your `Person` class. Any custom class you wish to encode, including when it is contained in a collection you are encoding, needs to implement `NSCoding`.

You'll need to implement `encodeWithCoder:` and `initWithCoder:`.

Here is the documentation for the `NSCoding` protocol:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will work.....

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
  {
   [aCoder encodeObject:_arrayOfPeople forKey:@"DataStoragePeopleArray"];
  }

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
   if(self = [super init]){
   self.yourpoperty = [aCoder decodeObjectforKey:@"DataStoragePeopleArray"];
  }
   return self;
  }
```